# Can you use tax_query with multiple post types in wp_query?

Tags: wordpress

Let's say I'm querying two post types, like so:

```
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => array('post', 'another_post_type'),
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'custom-taxonomy',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => 'test-slug',
                        )
                    )
                );
```

If I have `custom-taxonomy` linked to `another_post_type`, how would I run this query so that the `tax_query` only ran for the `another_post_type` posts? Basically I want the query to return all regular `post`, but only `another_post_type` posts with the category of `test-slug`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does that query not work as is? Do posts also have the 'custom-taxonomy'? If no posts return from that query try adding 'relation' => 'OR' to tax_query

Comment: @ngearing regular posts do not contain that custom taxonomy. Does not work as is, does not work with the OR relation. Both queries only return `another_post_type` posts with `test-slug` attached.

Comment: @ngearing I think I have found the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be working:

```
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => array('post', 'another_post_type'),
                'tax_query' => array(
                   'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'custom-taxonomy',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => 'test-slug'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category', # default post category
                        'operator' => 'EXISTS'
                    )
                )
            );
```